# Cloud caindo com 200 acessos simultâneos

Tags: php, apache, cloud

Tenho um cloud com a seguinte configuração: `Xeon E5420 8x 2.50Ghz, 5GB de ram SSD RAID 10 4x priority - 24 CPU Core e 6TB de banda`, mas quando atinge 150 a 200 acessos simultâneos ele começa a ficar lento e as vezes até cai o server, o que poderia ser feito para melhorar isso? Tenho outro server com a mesma configuração chego a ter pico de até 1300 acessos simultâneos e nunca aconteceu isso.

**Observação**: Sempre tem 60% livre de memoria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente adicionar/alterar isso no seu arquivo .htaccess

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    ServerLimit          40
    StartServers          2
    MaxClients          1000
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

Altere MaxClients para o número que desejar.

Você pode ser mais por aqui:
http://www.genericarticles.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=How_to_optimize_apache_web_server_for_maximum_concurrent_connections_or_increase_max_clients_in_apache